# Soma simples retornando NaN

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma simples soma em uma rotina:

```
var sum1 = $('input[name=hdValor01]').val(); // 40
var sum2 = $('input[name=hdValor02]').val(); // 
var sum3 = $('input[name=hdValor03]').val(); // 30
console.log(
    parseInt(sum1) + parseInt(sum2) + parseInt(sum3)
);
```

No console, está retornando NaN. Mas eles são números... sem os parseInts, ele está concatenando as variáveis.

Alguma ideia? Já tentei usar também valueOf(), sem sucesso.

Comment: Tens a certeza que todos têm um valor? tendo em conta que `parseInt('')` dá `NaN` seria mais seguro teres `...).val() || 0;` em todos os `sum`.

Comment: Como está a declaração dos teus inputs?

Comment: verifica antes se as variaveis possuem valores, creio que o parseInt na variável vazia está causando o NaN

Comment: Qual é o valor que você está usando em `sum2`? Não pode ser branco. `parseInt('')` dá `NaN`. E qualquer operação matemática com `NaN` dá `NaN`.

Comment: Então é isso mesmo... ela está em branco nos testes. Obrigado pela luz! Achei que convertia a zero quando a variável fosse nula ou vazia.

Comment: Converte pra 0 quando for nula ou vazia usando Math.abs()

Answer (score 4):

O operador OR(||) retornará o primeiro `valor == true`, como o retorno de um `ParseInt("") == Nan`, para o Javascript `NaN == false` será retornado o segundo valor da sua expressão, que no caso é 0, resolvendo o seu problema.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736476/how-to-turn-nan-from-parseint-into-0-for-an-empty-string

```js
var sum1 = $('input[name=hdValor01]').val(); // 40
var sum2 = $('input[name=hdValor02]').val(); // 
var sum3 = $('input[name=hdValor03]').val(); // 30
console.log(
    (parseInt(sum1) || 0) + 
    (parseInt(sum2) || 0) + 
    (parseInt(sum3) || 0)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="40" name="hdValor01">
<input type="text" value="" name="hdValor02">
<input type="text" value="30" name="hdValor03">
```

Answer (score 3):

Se o resultado é `NaN`, um dos termos da adição é `NaN`, pois todas as operações matemáticas envolvendo `NaN` dão resultado `NaN`. Como `parseInt('')` também dá `NaN`, eu diria que você está deixando pelo menos um dos campos em branco.

Se a intenção é permitir campos em branco, você vai precisar verificar cada termo antes de somar, utilizando a função `isNaN` – que é a única maneira de verificar se um valor é `NaN`, já que `NaN !== NaN`.

Comment: A segunda variável está em branco nos testes. Achei que convertia a zero quando a variável fosse nula ou vazia. Vou fazer um teste para convertê-la a 0 antes da soma então. Obrigado! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum1 = $('input[name=hdValor01]').val();
var sum2 = $('input[name=hdValor02]').val();
var sum3 = $('input[name=hdValor03]').val();
var somaProd = (Number(sum1) + Number(sum2) + Number(sum3));
```

Dessa maneira, deu certo! Converti todas as strings para números, inclusive a vazia.

Comment: Boa, não tinha me lembrado dessa opção.